# Pandas: Combining Product and Apply

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df created from a spreadsheet containing mostly strings:

```
         #             age sex   employed          educ marital   race
0    1  35 to 44 years   F  Full time      Some Col     DIV  White
1    2  65 to 74 years   M    Retired         BA/BS    SING  White
2    3  45 to 54 years   F  Full time         BA/BS     MAR   Hisp
```

I want to identify the most/least common combinations of values - perhaps an easy way being to calculate the frequency proportions in each column, and then look up the proportion for a given value and multiply all the proportions together (i.e. someone with a rare combination of values across these columns will have a very small number).

So I build a dict containing the frequencies:

```
frequencies = {col_name: frame[col_name].value_counts(normalize=True).to_dict() for col_name in columns[1:]}
```

Which produces output like `'sex': {'F': 0.5666666666666667, 'M': 0.43333333333333335}`

Now I know I need a function that with look up the frequency, and then I sense I'll need to combine `apply()`-ing that function with the `product()` method, but I'm stumped about how to do that -- mostly because I'm not sure how to construct and apply the frequency lookup function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following,

```
df.groupby(list(df.columns)).size()
```